# Update AWS S3 item ACL using new PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, guzzle

How can an item in S3 be updated with 'public-read' using the new AWS S3 PHP SDK: It would seem it is only possible to GET and PUT? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html

The iterator returns an array, not a class. Get object returns a class, but there are no obvious methods to update. CopyObject seems a bit of a hack?

```
$s3->copyObject(array(
        'Bucket'     => 'media',
        'Key'        => $k,
        'CopySource' => 'media'.'/'.$k,
        'ACL'        => 'public-read',
));
```

returns:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\InvalidRequestException: AWS Error Code: InvalidRequest, Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID: FC630F89A049823A, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: This copy request is illegal because it is trying to copy an object to itself without changing the object's metadata, storage class, website redirect location or encryption attributes., User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.5.3 Guzzle/3.8.1 curl/7.35.0 PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4 thrown in /.../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 91
```

Answer (score 4):

Better late than never.

```
$s3Client->putObjectAcl(array(
    'Bucket'     => 'yourbucket',
    'Key'        => 'yourkey',
    'ACL'    => 'public-read'
));
```